# android studio bumblebee Jetpack compose textfield error

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

i wrote an outlinedTextField and the "it" in onValueChange does not work along the label text

it does not read and Text also displays an error.

```
val usernameState = rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue) }

OutlinedTextField(
            value = usernameState.value,
            onValueChange = { usernameState.value = it },
            label = { Text(text = "username")}
        )
```

this is error for calling the outlinedTextfield and setting it up:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
> public fun OutlinedTextField(value: TextFieldValue, onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = ..., enabled: Boolean = ..., readOnly: Boolean = ..., textStyle: TextStyle = ..., label: (() -> Unit)? = ..., placeholder: (() -> Unit)? = ..., leadingIcon: (() -> Unit)? = ..., trailingIcon: (() -> Unit)? = ..., isError: Boolean = ..., visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = ..., keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = ..., keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = ..., singleLine: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = ..., shape: Shape = ..., colors: TextFieldColors = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material
> public fun OutlinedTextField(value: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = ..., enabled: Boolean = ..., readOnly: Boolean = ..., textStyle: TextStyle = ..., label: (() -> Unit)? = ..., placeholder: (() -> Unit)? = ..., leadingIcon: (() -> Unit)? = ..., trailingIcon: (() -> Unit)? = ..., isError: Boolean = ..., visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = ..., keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = ..., keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = ..., singleLine: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = ..., shape: Shape = ..., colors: TextFieldColors = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material

Comment: Kindly add code and error as text. More info on it - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: something like this?

Comment: How have you defined `usernameState`? Try always providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question.

Comment: yes i did : val usernameState = rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue) }

Comment: do you need a TextFieldValue? Or a String would be enough – there are two constructors. 
`val usernameState by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf("") }` then use this value in both `value` and `onValueChange` lambda (notice I've used `by` delegate to avoid using `value` getter)

Comment: i'm following a course which makes a copy of instagram. and i need values instead of string since im building auth page

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a `String` as a value with the signature that you are using there. Hence, the value parameter that you are passing should be `unserNameState.value.value`. The first value is to extract state value from `MutableState`, and the second is to extract the `String` from `TextFieldValue`. Also, you need to initialize the constructor of the `TextFieldValue` there by adding parenthesis to it.

My recommendation would be you go for the simplest approach.

```
var uns by remeberSaveable{ mutableStateOf("") } // Use 'by' to treat this state as a regular variable

OutlinedTextField(
 value = uns, // As simple as that
 onValueChange = { uns = it },
 label = { Text("User Name") }
)
```

Consider taking the [codelabs](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose) to gain a better overall understanding of Compose.

What have you sculpted on the Moon so far?

Comment: the problem is that im following a course and the course uses textfieldvalue instead of just string. I'm relatively new to android development and even newer to jetpack compose.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `remember` as

```
val usernameState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue) }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = usernameState.value,
    onValueChange = { usernameState.value = it },
    label = { Text(text = "username")}
)
```

or you can use Kotlin delegation as

```
val username by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue) }

OutlinedTextField(
    value = username,
    onValueChange = {username = it},
    label = {Text(text = "username")}
)
```

MutableState doesn't have getters and setters by default. To use Kotlin delegation, you have to import the necessary getters and setters (suggested by IDE) which are extension function for MutableState